# If - else statement does not work

Tags: php

do you have any idea why I can't get this to work? 
It does add up 19 always, regarding the condition...
( I am sure the $var is not set )

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST[artykuł4])) { 

  ".($total = $total + 19)."; 

} 

else 

{

".($total = $total + 0).";

} ?>
```

Comment: Did you mean `$_POST["artykuł4"]` ?

Comment: yes, the " ł " sign does not matter, working elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

your creating a string not doing a calculation

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST[artykuł4])) { 
   $total = $total + 19; 
} 
else 
{
   $total = $total + 0;//equivalent to just leaving the else out
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It works :) I can go to bed now, it's after midnight here. You saved my sleeping :)